# How to "fool" duck typing in Python

Tags: python, duck-typing

Suppose I had a class A:

```
 class A:

     def __init__(self, x, y):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y

     def sum(self):
         return self.x + self.y
```

And I defined a factory method called `factory`:

```
def factory(x, y):

    class B: pass

    b = B()
    setattr(b, 'x', x)
    setattr(b, 'y', y)
    B.__name__ = 'A'
    return b
```

Now, If I do `print(type(A(1, 2)))` and `print(type(factory(1, 2)))` they will show that these are different types. And if I try to do `factory(1, 2).sum()` I'll get an exception. But, `type(A).__name__` and `type(factory(1, 2)).__name__` are equivalent and if I do `A.sum(factory(1, 2))` I'll get 3, as if I was calling it using an `A`. So, my question is this:

What would I need to do here to make `factory(1, 2).sum()` work without defining `sum` on B or doing inheritance?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just return an `A`? Of course the names are equivalent: you explicitly made it that way.

Comment: @MattMessersmith This came about as the result of somebody asking me to deserialize some JSON into an object without providing the class. I was wondering if I could use the object the same way

Comment: I'm not sure that answers what I asked. If you just return an `A` your factory function will work like you want it to...

Comment: If you don't know the class you're deserializing, how would you know what methods are on it / what methods to call?

Comment: @MattMessersmith That's a good point and I didn't really think the situation all the way through. If I were to make an analogy to statically-typed, object oriented languages, it'd be like deserializing to an interface but Python doesn't really do those.

Comment: Even so, I'm still curious to see how someone would do it

Comment: But you can't deserialize to an interface, because there'd be no way of knowing which implementation of a method to call.  Pretend you had three classes A, B, C that all implemented an interface with a method 'sum', but did so differently.  Which sum implementation would you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding the factory pattern, and possibly getting confused with how interfaces work in Python. Either that, or *I* am fundamentally confused by the question. Either way, there's some sorting out we need to do.

> What would I need to do here to make factory(1, 2).sum() work without
>   defining sum on B or doing inheritance?

Just return an `A` instead of some other type:

```
def factory(x, y):
    return A(x, y)
```

then

```
print(factory(1,2).sum())
```

will output `3` as expected. But that's kind of a useless factory...could just do `A(x, y)` and be done with it!

Some notes:

1. You typically use a "factory" (or factory pattern) when you have easily "nameable" types that may be non-trivial to construct. Consider how when you use `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d)) there's an option for `kind`, which is basically an enum for all the different strategies you might use to do an interpolation. This is, in essence, a factory (but hidden inside the function for ease of use). You could imagine this could be standalone, so you'd call your "strategy" factory, and then pass this on to the `interp1d` call. However, doing it inline is a common pattern in Python. Observe: These strategies are easy to "name", somewhat hard to construct in general (you can imagine it would be annoying to have to pass in a function that does linear interpolation as opposed to just doing `kind='linear'`). That's what makes the factory pattern useful...
2. If you don't know what `A` is up front, then it's definitely not the factory pattern you'd want to apply. Furthermore, if you don't know what you're serializing/deserializing, it would be impossible to call it or use it. You'd have to know that, or have some way of inferring it.
3. Interfaces in Python are *not* enforced like they are in other languages like Java/C++. That's the spirit of duck typing. If an interface does something like call `x.sum()`, then it doesn't matter what type `x` actually is, it just has to have a method called `sum()`. If it acts like the "sum" duck, quacks like the "sum" duck, then it *is* the "sum" duck from Python's perspective. Doesn't matter if `x` is a `numpy` array, or `A`, it'll work all the same. In Java/C++, stuff like that *wont compile* unless the compiler is *absolutely certain* that `x` has the method `sum` defined. Fortunately Python isn't like that, so you can even define it on the fly (which maybe you were trying to do with `B`). Either way, interfaces are a much different concept in Python than in other mainstream languages.

P.S.

> But, `type(A).__name__` and `type(factory(1, 2)).__name__` are equivalent

Of *course* they are, you explicitly do this when you say `B.__name__ = 'A'`. So I'm not sure what you were trying to get at there...

HTH!